# Test class with custom setting

Tags: trigger, unit-test, customsetting

I' have written a trigger on lead, very simple.
I'am using the custom setting for the first tine to avoid hard coding or query to get ids.
I haven't experience testing custom setting.

I have a problem with my test class,i get the following error:

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

reference line for the error is `l.OwnerId=cs.OwnerId__c;`

Plase can you take a look to my test class code:

MY TRIGGER:

```
    trigger LeadSetOwner on Lead (before update) {

       //GET USER ID AND RECORD TYPE ID FROM CUSTOM SETTINGS.
       SetOwner__c cs = SetOwner__c.getValues('standardset');

        for (Lead l: Trigger.new){

            //GET OLD LEAD'S RECORD
            Lead  oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);

            //CHECK IF LEAD STATUS IS CHANGED TO 'Archived' OR 'False'        
            if ((l.Status=='Archived' || l.Status=='False'||l.Status=='Lead - Never') && (oldLead.Status!= l.Status)) {                                              
                     l.Archived_Original_Owner__c = l.OwnerId;
                       // ASSIGN LEAD TO THE USER Anna Forsgren Kap
                     l.OwnerId=cs.OwnerId__c;
                       //SAVE OLD RECORD TYPE AND SET RECORD TYPE ARCHIVED
                     l.OldRecordType__c=oldLead.recordtypeId;
                     l.recordtypeid=cs.RecordtypeID__c;
                    }                

             else  if ((l.Status<>'Archived' || l.Status<>'False'||l.Status<>'Lead - Never' )  && (oldLead.Status != l.Status)&&(l.Archived_Original_Owner__c!=null) ) {                        
                 l.OwnerId= l.Archived_Original_Owner__c;
                // SET OLD RECORD TYPE
                // CONDITION OLD RECORD TYPE NOT NULL
                If (oldlead.OldRecordType__c!=null){
                l.recordtypeid=oldlead.OldRecordType__c;
                                                   }                      
            }
        }
     }


MY TEST CLASS:

@isTest
private class TestLeadSetOwner {


    static testMethod void TestLeadSetOwner() {

        Test.setMock(WebserviceMock.class, new DevQlikViewWebServiceMockImpl());


        Profile p = [SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator' limit 1];
        User u2 =new User( Alias = 'newUser1' ,
                        Email ='newuser123@testorg.com',
                        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                        LastName = 'Testing',
                        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                        LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                        UserName='newuser123@testorg.com',
                        ProfileId=p.Id,
                        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles'); 

        // TEST CUSTOM SETTING 

         SetOwner__c mycs = SetOwner__c.getValues('standardset'); 
         if(mycs == null) {             
             mycs = new SetOwner__c(Name= 'CustomValues');
             mycs.OwnerId__c ='00520000000z3PrAAI';
             mycs.RecordtypeID__c='012L00000004QsrIAE';
             insert mycs;
         }     

        //CREATE A LEAD 1
       // System.runAs(u2) {               
            Lead lead = createNewLead(mycs.OwnerId__c);                      
            lead.Archived_Original_Owner__c = mycs.OwnerId__c;           
            insert lead;

            //CREATE A LEAD 2
            Lead lead2 = createNewLead(mycs.OwnerId__c);
            insert lead2;

            test.startTest();

            lead.Status = 'Unqualified';
            lead.OldRecordType__c= mycs.RecordtypeID__c;
            update lead;


            lead2.Status = 'false';
            update lead2;

            lead.Status = 'Contacted';
            lead.OwnerId=lead.Archived_Original_Owner__c;
            update lead;

            test.stopTest();        
        }
   // }

    private static Lead createNewLead(Id ownerId) {
        Lead lead = new Lead();
        lead.OwnerId = ownerId;
        lead.LastName = 'last';
        lead.FirstName = 'First';
        lead.Company = 'Company';
        lead.Status = 'NewStatus';
        lead.IsUnreadByOwner = True;
        lead.Country='Sweden';
        lead.Email='shshdkjd@fkfk.fi';
        lead.Phone='3333';
        lead.MobilePhone='3333';
        lead.Switchboard__c='3333';
        return lead;        
    }


}
```

Thank you very much.
BR.

Comment: yes, dummy data.This  because i want avoid the use of seealldata=true in my test class

Answer (score 1):

You are not inserting records into your customsetting with the name 'standardset' as your looking for a record with name 'standardset' but your test record inserts with name 'CustomValues'

```
if(mycs == null) {             
         mycs = new SetOwner__c(Name= 'CustomValues');
         // Above line should be changed to 
         mycs = new SetOwner__c(Name= 'standardset');
         mycs.OwnerId__c ='00520000000z3PrAAI';
         mycs.RecordtypeID__c='012L00000004QsrIAE';
         insert mycs;
     }
```

Note: Its a bad practice to  hardcode ids. Create your own test data by inserting records in the test class and use those ids instead or if you have seeAllData= true then you can query it from existing data.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I have tried this solution how second option. My first working test was with a query and seealldata=true. But i didn't want make a query in my test class.I know that I have always try to avoid the use of seealldata = true because yours is a test dependent on data in the sandbox.So i have tried to use fake ids in my test class.What do you think about? thanks.

Comment: RecordTypeIds you should get by querying the SObject `RecordType` - the recordType.developerName should be invariant between your PROD and sandbox.  Recordtypes are part of configuration data. The ownerId comes from User records. If you need a specific User with certain field values, create it in your test method. If you don't care, use UserInfo.getUserId() to get the running user

Comment: hardcoding recordtypeIds is also bad practice