# Custom setting value in test class

Tags: customsetting

When i am running a test class values from customsetting is always comming false.Although it is true.

I am not able to figure out the exact reason for that.
Please advice

Comment: you have to initialize you custom [setttings](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/test-class-with-custom-setting)

Comment: otherwise you could use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` but this is bad practice

Comment: i am doing initializing still value is comming flase..  Trigger_Run_Logic__c cs=new Trigger_Run_Logic__c();
        cs.RunClassObjectTrigger__c=true;'

Comment: please paste some code, custom sett initialization and getting part

Comment: do you do `insert cs;` ? where is the custom setting name ?

Comment: Thank you so much @llya Lepesh..I was not inserting it...it works now..Thankyou again

Comment: use: insert new Trigger_Run_Logic__c(RunClassObjectTrigger__c = true, name = 'test'); will have one line

Answer (score 3):

@David, custom settings must be inserted, same approach you would take to create SObject records during test setup.

```
@isTest
public class testClass {

    @testSetup static void createTestData() {
        Trigger_Run_Logic__c cs = new Trigger_Run_Logic__c();
        cs.RunClassObjectTrigger__c = true;
        insert cs;
    }

    static testmethod void testMethod1() {
        Trigger_Run_Logic__c cs = Trigger_Run_Logic__c.getInstance();
        System.assertEquals(true, cs.RunClassObjectTrigger__c);        
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `createTestdata`, you can just call `Trigger_Run_Logic__c.getOrgDefaults()` and then insert it. I find that clearer than just inserting a new one

Comment: Valid approach. But since OP did not mention RunClassObjectTrigger__c was default TRUE I wanted to illustrate a full "set, insert, and assert" example. Using "Trigger_Run_Logic__c.getOrgDefaults()" instead of "new Trigger_Run_Logic__c()" actually adds characters to my example :) and I opted for brevity. Finally, a word of caution... using system assertions with a custom setting pulled directly from org defaults may get you into trouble (e.g. failing test classes) if all orgs do not share the same values. And they often won't.